# How to use the value of a counter to find a column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns in Excel, named

> "Volume1"
>     "Volume2"
>     "Volume3"
>     "Volume4"

I have a counter from 1 to 4.

I want to give my variable `Vol`a value depending on the name of my column.

I did this :

```
For j = 1 To 4
    Vol = Application.Match("Volume" + " & j & ", Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:K1"), 0)
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - your concatenation is out

```
For j = 1 To 4
    Vol = Application.Match("Volume" & j, Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:K1"), 0)
Next
```

*better approach using Find*

```
Dim rng1 As Range
For j = 1 To 4
   Set rng1 = Sheets("Results").Range("A1:K1").Find("Volume" & j, , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng1.Address
Next
```